# countinue a method after Executors.newFixedThreadPool finish's its job

Tags: android, android-thread

I have a method. inside this method I run a task by Executors. its work is fetch data from server and fill an results Arraylist.

```
   public Paginator(String secSrv, int total, ExecutorService executorService, Cookie cookie) {
    securitySrv = secSrv;
    totalItems = total;
    this.executorService = executorService;
    this.cookie = cookie;
}

ArrayList<Suser> results = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<Suser> generatePage(int currentPage) {

    fetchAllUsers(currentPage);
    ......
    for (int i = startItem; i < startItem + numOfData; i++) {
            pageData.add(results.get(i-1));
        }
```

after filling results Arraylist i have to use this arraylist.how coud i know where executorService finished its job and I can continue my method again?

```
   private void fetchAllUsers(final int currentPage) {

    Runnable fetchUserListFromSrv = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
            JSONObject count = new JSONObject();
            try {
                count.put("count", 10);
                count.put("page", currentPage);
                String SearchUsersPagingResult = ...
                results.addAll(susers) ;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    executorService.submit(fetchUserListFromSrv);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use documentation. All answers are here.

[Future| Android developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

[ExecutorService| Android developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: dude I change my code to this and everything is ok.http://codepad.org/C9swPyU5 . can you explain to me, does this method hold a main thread and after finish its job then resume the main thread?

Comment: A Future represents the result of an asynchronous computation.The Callable interface is similar to Runnable, in that both are designed for classes whose instances are potentially executed by another thread. So , answer to your question is NO , method fetchAllUsers() doesn't block Main thread.

Comment: Ok, but why other code into main method `generatePage(int currentPage)` does not execute till my thread finished its job? if these codes into main method is executed I got error?